# How can I restrict access (by IP) to devices behind my Edge Router?

Tags: ubiquiti, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have a Ubiquiti ERPro-8 with some servers behind it. I would like to allow access to those servers, on specific ports. But I would like to restrict access to those servers by IP address.

For example:

Allow access to 10.0.1.40:8080 from 123.456.789.1/32.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with an `iptables` setup on each of your servers. Something along the lines of

```
iptables -J INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 123.456.789.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I didn't even think about IP tables... Thanks!